# How to open incoming port 50070 in firewall (google compute engine)

Tags: hadoop, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have my Single node Hadoop installed on Google Compute Engine instance and i want to open port 50070 on that machine to access the hadoop dashboard. i configured in the firewall rule as **tcp:50070** in compute engine networks. but still i am unable to access my port outside the network (ie . via internet). I tried nmap for the public ip of my GCE instance and i got a result which has only ssh port got opened all other ports are filtered .

Note: i am using debian 7.5 image

Comment: Naveen, could you provide the information about your instance and firewall with: ``gcloud compute instances describe <instance-name> --zone <zone>`` ``gcloud compute firewall-rules describe <firewall-name>``

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your daemon is listening on port 50070. If you have more than one networks in you project make sure the port is opened on the right network. You can run the following commands to check the information about your instance and network.
    lsof -i 
    gcutil --project= getinstance 
    gcutil --project= listnetworks
    gcutil --project= listfirewalls
    gcutil --project= getfirewall

Comment: I tried nmap -p 50070 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx from my desktop machine i got message as filtered.. (50070/tcp filtered unknown)  But when i tried this from my another cloud machine which was connected to the same network i got message as open.(50070/tcp open unknown)

Comment: Naveen, can you share the output of gcutil --project=<project> listfirewalls?  That might help us debug this further.

Answer (score 0):

Check if IP/Port is allowed in iptables or not.

```
iptables -L
```

would show you all the records.

To allow port in iptables you can do the following:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 50070 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables-save -c
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

In addition to configure the firewall rule at GCE web console make sure that your server is listening at **0.0.0.0** instead of **127.0.0.1**

## Long answer

> In the context of servers, **0.0.0.0** means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. If a host has two IP addresses, **192.168.1.1** and **10.1.2.1**, and a server running on the host listens on **0.0.0.0**, it will be reachable at both of those IPs - [Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/)

In contrast **127.0.0.1** is the IP address used to stablish a connection to the same machine used by the user this address is usually referred as the localhost.

> It's often used when you want a network-capable application to only serve clients on the same host. A process that is listening on 127.0.0.1 for connections will only receive local connections on that socket. - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Hence, if you try to stablish a connection to your server from internet and your server is listening at 127.0.0.1 at your GCE machine, then, from the server point of view a request has never been received and as a consequence Goocle Cloud Firewall will refuse the connection because there is no server listening at the opened port (in your case **50070**).

I hope this answer helps to solve your problem. Best regards.