# How to open php web server in browser from docker container?

Tags: php, docker, apache, containers, docker-container

So, I have running php web server inside docker container like so `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000`. How can I open it via browser in my computer?

I was trying `docker run -p 4200:8000 <image_id>`, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you set a Docker container to listen on the container-private 127.0.0.1 address, it won't be reachable from outside its container.  Does `CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` work better?  (Also see [Docker with php built-in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591413/docker-with-php-built-in-server).)

Comment: @DavidMaze `CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` didn't work, but thanks for an answer. Question that you sent might be helpful.