# Python's SocketServer won''t handshake

Tags: python, tcp, wireshark, handshake, socketserver

## The problem

I am trying to use the [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#module-SocketServer) that ships with Python but I have some issues in the handshake phase. The handshake works fine as long as I use localhost or 127.0.0.1. However when I put the IP of my eth0 card it just won't handshake. I test the official example code [found here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example):

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        print self.data
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Terminal snippet:

```
manos@box:~$ netcat 10.2.203.26 9999
manos@box:~$
manos@box:~$ netcat localhost 9999
test
```

As you see in the snippet, trying to connect to `10.2.293.26` which is the IP of my network card doesn't work. As soon as I try to connect to `localhost`, it works fine!

On Wireshark I get a `[RST, ACK]` after the first SYN being sent from the client to the server (in the initial handshake phase).

## Works fine with telnet

My first guess was that this was a router resetting the connection. However that is not the case since I can `telnet` fine:

Terminal 1:

```
manos@box:~/tmp/test$ netcat -l 9999
(waiting)
test
```

Terminal 2:

```
manos@box:~$ netcat 10.2.203.26 9999
test
```

Comment: Just a quick suggestion, have you set up port forwarding correctly?

Comment: @redspidermkv Well `telneting` wouldn't work if that was the issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding to `localhost`, which doesn't allow specifying the IP address/es of the machine's interface/s as the destination on the connecting host.

You should specify `0.0.0.0` or the empty string as the machine's address in the bind operation (the `HOST` argument in your example) in order to allow the remote host to specify any of the machine's IP addresses as the destination.

For more information about the difference between `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/3903832) or to [this one](https://superuser.com/a/196898).