# Connect to localhost:3000 from another computer | expressjs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, localhost

I'm currently working on a project and I would like to test it from another computer or phone. This computer is connected on the same network.

How can I connect to  `http://localhost:3000`?

I'm using `expressjs` (`nodejs` module ) as server.

Comment: Try using the IP Address? Depending on how your network is set up the computer name may work also.

Comment: This seems to be a [pretty heavily duplicated](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3AStackoverflow.com+connect+to+localhost+from+another+computer&oq=site%3AStackoverflow.com+connect+to+localhost+from+another+computer+&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.5946j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) question.

Comment: Not duplcated he use xamp server but im not use it, i use `expressjs`

Comment: The principles are exactly the same. You have a server listening. You connect to it from a client. It doesn't matter what software that server is (so long as you haven't configured it to **only** listen on the loopback interface, but you haven't shown us enough information to tell about that).

Comment: @Quentin , when i get my ip adress 192.168.1.x and i access to thos adress from external device it not work ! ( i need to access on port 3000 )

Comment: @Reda — Well, yes. If you need port 3000 then you need port 3000.

Comment: What, precisely, doesn't work? Is your Node app configured to listen on interfaces other than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: tht what im looking for :) !

Comment: In support for this question... Changing `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` fixed my issue. I didn't get this info on any other "duplicate" questions.

Comment: A very helpful explanation about 0.0.0.0:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/2909851

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Configure your application to run on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.0(localhost)`. For example:

```
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 3000);
});
```

Then from another computer, connect to `192.168.1.11:3000` (or whatever your local IP address is).

Comment: This answered its look logic, but it not work for me :3' ! , when i access to 0.0.0.0:3000, **Unable to connect**

Comment: You need to access `192.168.1.11:3000`(or whatever your address is), **not** `0.0.0.0:3000`.

Comment: Is changing `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` a general practice for any server?? Or is it just for node.js??

Comment: Thank, it works! Can somebody explain why?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not working. I have changed my application to listen to 0.0.0.0 and trying to access my application from another computer using this url `192.168.1.11:3000.` but this is not working. It keeps on showing this site can't be reached

and btw I'm using reactjs

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown, or non-applicable target (a ‘no particular address’ place holder).
In the context of a route entry, it usually means the default route.

In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. If a host has two IP addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs. @Luckylooke
For more info you can see: https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/

Comment: @Bidhan it works between the devices which are in the same wifi. but, how can i connect to server i m running on my computer through web?

Comment: @Workers You will need to expose your local server to the web. You can use something like ngrok for this.

Answer (score 16):

your url should look like

```
http://yourcomputername:3000
```

to get computer name open command prompt windows and type hostname then hit enter

Comment: Yes, this is what finally worked for me on macOS Sierra. I had been doing `http://<name>.local:3000` but it is JUST the computer name: `http://doug:3000` that worked for me

Comment: @Yuri's approach also works on Mac, by opening Terminal and typing `hostname`

Answer (score 15):

Given that the port is bind to any IP address other than 127.0.0.1 (localhost), you can access it from any other system.

To view your IP addresses, use `ipconfig` (Windows) or `ifconfig` (Linux) command.
Find out the IP which is in the same network as the "other system" from which you want access.
Then access it like, for example: `172.16.0.12:3000`.

PS: Remember to include the port `3000` even when accessing it through another system. Also, hostnames may be used in place of IP addresses, if configured.

Comment: absolutely correct logic.Well explained.