# How to connect to a node js web server from another computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

Is there anyway to connect to a web server of node js from another computer that connected to same wifi?
i searched i get these results:
[Connect to localhost:3000 from another computer | expressjs, nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712141/connect-to-localhost3000-from-another-computer-expressjs-nodejs)
but all didnt worked can you help me?
 thanks!

this question fixed
Now I want to connect my server to a domain for example:alireza.com
How can i listen to that host name with my server
Thanks!

Comment: you have to take your ip address from the node + port server
otherwise you can turn off the firewall and retest

Comment: i did but it didnt worked

Comment: you know what im confused from? im confused from that the other computer's ip is not same as this computer's ip that i created the server on it when i connected both of them to 1 wifi

Comment: Get your current ip address in the network by typing ipconfig in the cmd if you are a windows user, then from the other computer: ip:port

Comment: i did it but it didnt worked again

Comment: that computer's ip or server's computer ip?

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524116/accessing-localhost-xampp-from-another-computer-over-lan-network-how-to

Comment: I've same issue before and I fixed by this way:
1- Use IP address instead localhost e.g:192.168.1.100 
2- use right protocol: "http" or "https"

Comment: It fixed just my firewall was on

Comment: how can i close the question to they dont answer?

Comment: I don't mean to be... well, mean, but if you are confused by 2 machines not having the same IP on the same network, you should begin by studying a bit of networking before trying to create a web application. If you struggle with localhost, it's gonna be a real nightmare when the production stuff will come.

Comment: how can i make it global?

Comment: when everyone around the world when connect to a domain could play with my program?

Comment: im very new to networking my first networking project was on unity

Comment: Many use the "ngrok" service for letting another computer on the internet access the development server. 
Another common way is to develop in a cloud environment like glitch.com, where each project start with a url to access the server.

Comment: i have a cloud environment its name is partporsa.ir(ir because website is iranian)

Comment: i think i need to create a new question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.