# Make NodeJS listen on 127.0.0.1/abc:8080

Tags: node.js

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running with Apache and NodeJS server. The Apache server is listening on port 80 and 443. A PHP File is executed by the Apache server and is located at: **http://server-ip/abc/index.php**. It does a Post-Request to the NodeJS sever:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:8080/', false, $context);

//do something with $result
```

The NodeJS Server (script below) should read the Post-Parameters, do something with it an return a string.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   //do something
   //return something
}).listen(8080);
```

When the PHP Script tries to connect to the NodeJS server, i get the CORS same origin error.

Comment: It is not possible to do 127.0.0.1/abc:8080. I think you should use another port like 8000 or something else if your apache is running on 8080

Comment: Please provide details of about what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: This helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715797/how-to-use-the-optional-hostname-parameter-in-node-js-server-listen

Comment: @krishnasapkal i rewrited my question.

Comment: really don't get the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly you can't start **NodeJS** serve on specific route location, but you can resolve your problem in two way:

First one is with enabling **CORS** like below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

or use package like [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), for more info visit this [link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

The second one is that config Apache to server your Nodejs application behind a proxy like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>     
     ServerName example.com    
     ServerAlias www.example.com     
     ProxyPreserveHost On 
     ProxyPass /node http://example.com:3000/node 
     ProxyPassReverse /node http://example.com:3000/node
</VirtualHost>
```

More info and same issue for how to serve and config **Apache** for **NodeJS** server behind the proxy visit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259321/apache-node-js-mod-proxy-how-to-route-one-domain-to-3000-and-another-to-8#answer-14260011).

Comment: i will try the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

The port is always defined right after the host. So `127.0.0.1/abc:8080` is nothing else as `127.0.0.1:80/abc:8080` where `abc:8080` is handled as a path. You have to bind nodeJs to another port when 8080 is already in use.