# Websockets Address on Internal Network need's static ip?

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, network-programming, localhost

I'm running a Go webserver using `Gorilla/websocket` for a real-time chess/chat application. As far as I know, I define the **address** and **port** in two locations, the Go `http.ListenAndServer()` method and the Javascript `new Websocket();` function. This works great accross browsers on the same host machine, but it gets tricky when trying to extend the functionality over my internal network. So I use, for instance:

Go:

```
PORT := "0.0.0.0:8080"
// ...
http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    h.serveWs(hub, w, r) // h is a chessboard Handler wrapper
})
//...
http.ListenAndServe(PORT, nil)
```

Javascript:

```
conn = new WebSocket("ws://0.0.0.0:8080/ws");
```

In my effort to get this working on different devices over the network I've tried using, instead of the `0.0.0.0` address, `localhost` or my `hostname` and my host's internal ip (e.g.) `10.232.44.20`; With the latter, the internal ip hardcoded in, it works, but the other attempts don't. I thought that using `0.0.0.0` would accept all connections from within the network, which I gathered from this answer:
[What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

How should I program `ListenAndServe` as well as `new Websocket` so that I can access the server within the internal network, without having to hardcode my internal ip address? Should I access that number programmatically from Js and Go? In the end, I want to be able to run this server on a variety of networks, without configuration, and have it *just work*. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the web page and websocket endpoints are served by the same host, then create the websocket using the host used to fetch the web page:

```
conn = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws");
```

This will just work in all network configurations.

As far as the Go code is concerned, the easiest approach is to listen on all networks:

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```