# Active MQ warnings filling up logs

Tags: activemq-classic

I see the below in Active MQ logs all the time and its filling up the log files and making to difficult to read useful log messages. What does this warning mean and how do I fix this? I tried some solutions that I found using google, but none of them helped. Can you help me understand what this log means and how do I fix this? Active MQ version 5.13.0 64 bit Windows 2012

```
    2018-04-26 16:43:22,072 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60736 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:60736@61616
    2018-04-26 16:48:18,554 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50693 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50693@61616
    2018-04-26 16:48:18,554 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50690 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50690@61616
    2018-04-26 16:48:18,554 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50689 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50689@61616
    2018-04-26 16:48:18,554 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50553 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50553@61616
```

Below ismy activemq.xml config

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="EnvironmentName" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <!--managementContext createConnector="false"/ -->
        <managementContext createConnector="true" connectorPort="1616"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" dataSource="#oracle-ds"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    <plugins>
            <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq" />
            <authorizationPlugin>
                <map>
                  <authorizationMap>
                    <authorizationEntries>
                        <authorizationEntry queue="*.>"
                                            read="admins"
                                            write="admins"
                                            admin="admins" />
                        <authorizationEntry queue="sysQuename"
                                          read="admins,sysusergrp"
                                          write="admins,syssgrp"
                                          admin="admins" />
            <authorizationEntry queue="AnotherQueue"
                                          read="admins,anothergroup"
                                          write="admins,anothergroup"
                                          admin="admins" />

                        <!-- <authorizationEntry topic="*.>"
                                          read="all"
                                          write="all"
                                          admin="all" /> -->
            <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="admins,users,sysusergrp,anothergroup" write="admins,users, sysusergrp, anothergroup" admin="admins,users,sysusergrp,anothergroup"/>
            <authorizationEntry topic="Topic1" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/>
            <authorizationEntry topic="Topic2" read="admins" write="admins" admin="admins"/>
                    </authorizationEntries>
                    <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
                        <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry
                                          read="all"
                                          write="all"
                                          admin="all"/>
                    </tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
                  </authorizationMap>
                </map>
            </authorizationPlugin>
        </plugins>


    </broker>

    <!-- Oracle DataSource Sample Setup -->

      <bean id="oracle-ds" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!--property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>-->
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port/schema"/>
        <property name="user" value="username"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <!--<property name="maxTotal" value="200"/>-->
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="MinLimit">0</prop>
                <prop key="MaxLimit">100</prop>
            </props>
        </property>     
            <!--<property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>-->
        <!--<property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>-->
     </bean>
    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Below is the startup log of MQ

```
 2018-04-26 16:58:27,089 | INFO  | Database adapter driver override recognized for : [oracle_jdbc_driver] - adapter: class org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.OracleJDBCAdapter | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:27,682 | INFO  | Database lock driver override not found for : [oracle_jdbc_driver].  Will use default implementation. | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:27,682 | INFO  | Attempting to acquire the exclusive lock to become the Master broker | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:27,698 | INFO  | Becoming the master on dataSource: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource@730d22e3 | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.DefaultDatabaseLocker | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,073 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (BrokerName, ID:HOSTNAME-49282-1524776307714-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,385 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://HOSTNAME:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,385 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,401 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: amqp://HOSTNAME:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,401 | INFO  | Connector amqp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,401 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: stomp://HOSTNAME:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,401 | INFO  | Connector stomp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,417 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: mqtt://HOSTNAME:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,448 | INFO  | Connector mqtt started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,448 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49298 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49298@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:28,448 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49287 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49287@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:28,542 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49311 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49311@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:28,589 | INFO  | jetty-9.2.13.v20150730 | org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,651 | INFO  | Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@-7d7eba88{/,null,AVAILABLE} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,698 | INFO  | Started ServerConnector@b2498261{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:61614} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,698 | INFO  | Started @5125ms | org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,714 | INFO  | Listening for connections at ws://HOSTNAME:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,714 | INFO  | Connector ws started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,714 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.13.0 (BrokerName, ID:HOSTNAME-49282-1524776307714-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,714 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,714 | WARN  | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: D:\Apps\apache-activemq-5.13.0\bin\win64\..\..\data\BrokerName only has 16672 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 16672 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,729 | WARN  | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: D:\Apps\apache-activemq-5.13.0\bin\win64\..\..\data\BrokerName\tmp_storage only has 16672 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 16672 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:28,729 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49283 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49283@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:28,839 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49285 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49285@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:28,854 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49284 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49284@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:28,885 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49286 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49286@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:28,964 | INFO  | jetty-9.2.13.v20150730 | org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,182 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /admin | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,339 | INFO  | Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 26 16:58:29 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy | org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,339 | INFO  | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webconsole-embedded.xml] | org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,354 | INFO  | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webconsole-query.xml] | org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,401 | INFO  | Loading properties file from URL [file:path/apache-activemq-5.13.0/bin/win64/../../conf/credentials.properties] | org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,432 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,432 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,510 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,510 | INFO  | FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started | org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,526 | INFO  | Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Apr 26 16:58:29 EDT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext | org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,526 | INFO  | Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] | org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,589 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/createDestination.action] onto handler '/createDestination.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,589 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/deleteDestination.action] onto handler '/deleteDestination.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,589 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/createSubscriber.action] onto handler '/createSubscriber.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,589 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/deleteSubscriber.action] onto handler '/deleteSubscriber.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,589 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/sendMessage.action] onto handler '/sendMessage.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,604 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/purgeDestination.action] onto handler '/purgeDestination.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,604 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/deleteMessage.action] onto handler '/deleteMessage.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,604 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/copyMessage.action] onto handler '/copyMessage.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,604 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/moveMessage.action] onto handler '/moveMessage.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,604 | INFO  | Mapped URL path [/deleteJob.action] onto handler '/deleteJob.action' | org.apache.activemq.web.handler.BindingBeanNameUrlHandlerMapping | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,870 | INFO  | FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 344 ms | org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,870 | INFO  | Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6c5fb9bf{/admin,file:/G:apache-activemq-5.13.0/webapps/admin/,AVAILABLE} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,886 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Console at http://ServerConnector@7c9374b6{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8162}/admin | org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:29,979 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /api | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:30,136 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed | /api | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:30,636 | INFO  | Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3e4a58c7{/api,file:/G:apache-activemq-5.13.0/webapps/api/,AVAILABLE} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:30,651 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ REST API at http://ServerConnector@7c9374b6{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8162}/api | org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:30,698 | INFO  | Started ServerConnector@7c9374b6{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8162} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:30,714 | INFO  | Started @7141ms | org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2018-04-26 16:58:31,401 | INFO  | Connector vm://BrokerName started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///AnotherIPADDRESS:59235@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:31,401 | INFO  | Started responder end of duplex bridge NC@ID:ANOTHERHOST-59849-1523762308916-0:1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///AnotherIPADDRESS:59235@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:31,417 | INFO  | Network connection between vm://BrokerName#0 and tcp:///AnotherIPADDRESS:59235@61616 (Broker2) has been established. | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp:///AnotherIPADDRESS:59235@61616, localBroker= vm://BrokerName#0
2018-04-26 16:58:33,386 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49587 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49587@61616
2018-04-26 16:58:33,401 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:49599 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:49599@61616
2018-04-26 16:59:43,090 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:54942 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:54942@61616
2018-04-26 16:59:49,247 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://IPADDRESS:55398 failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///IPADDRESS:55398@61616
2018-04-26 17:02:34,183 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50568 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50568@61616
2018-04-26 17:02:34,183 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50567 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50567@61616
2018-04-26 17:02:34,183 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50565 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50565@61616
2018-04-26 17:02:34,183 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50328 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:50328@61616
2018-04-26 17:03:34,626 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55409 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:55409@61616
2018-04-26 17:03:34,626 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55408 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:55408@61616
2018-04-26 17:03:34,626 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55197 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:55197@61616
2018-04-26 17:03:34,626 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55407 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:55407@61616
2018-04-26 17:04:22,626 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:59165 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:59165@61616
2018-04-26 17:04:22,626 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:59164 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:59164@61616
2018-04-26 17:04:22,626 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:59163 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:59163@61616
2018-04-26 17:04:22,642 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58999 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58999@61616
```

Comment: similar one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915818/warning-as-java-io-eofexception-when-activemq-starts

Answer (score 1):

It gives you information about the connection change(conection timeout, for example).

If it occurs too often, you'd better check your code on the client side. Normally, one client should reuse 1 or several connections with the broker, maybe you create too much connections.

Comment: I will check with our developers as I am not sure how they are managing connections. Also we use resource adapter from redhat for some of our apps to connect to Active MQ. Any idea what resource adapter settings I should look at to fix these messages