# MongoDB database service does not start

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB.

[Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) I did everything on this page in order, but the service doesn't start and it gives this error:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-01-16 21:25:33 +03; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 4045 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 4045 (code=exited, status=48)

Jan 16 21:25:33 vbot systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jan 16 21:25:33 vbot systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
Jan 16 21:25:33 vbot systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use https://askubuntu.com/ forum instead. You can use your stackoverflow login as it's part of stack exchange sites

Comment: can you add your config file ?

Comment: See if this solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072651/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code-48/42072766