# MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri in Mac M1

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

Getting MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri ERROR in Macbook with M1 chip.

In terminal, I followed the following steps to install Mongo:

1. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
2. `brew install mongodb-community@5.0` to install MongoDB.
3. To Start Mongo `sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb/`

Now, while using Mongoose in project with URI: `mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name` getting the above error.

EDIT:
Adding full error:

> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.522+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire
> specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.524+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling
> TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols
> 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.524+05:30"},"s":"W",
> "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer
> configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.524+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen in use."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.525+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.525+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.525+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.525+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":38271,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Archits-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.525+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,
> "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName}
> unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.extfeatures"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.525+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.526+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.1.0"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.526+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.526+05:30"},"s":"E",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error
> setting up
> listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address
> already in use"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.526+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the
> ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MirrorMaestro"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the WaitForMajorityService"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the global connection pool"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all
> outstanding egress activity."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down free monitoring"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the HealthLog"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the TTL monitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring
> the global lock for shutdown"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache
> for shutdown"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down full-time data capture"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now
> exiting"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:23:34.527+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down","attr":{"exitCode":48}} archit@Archits-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo
> pkill -f mongod
>
> archit@Archits-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongod
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.427+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling
> TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols
> 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.428+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire
> specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.430+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.430+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen in use."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":38692,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Archits-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,
> "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName}
> unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.extfeatures"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.1.0"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.431+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"E",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException
> in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data
> directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify
> another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by
> adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the
> ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MirrorMaestro"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the WaitForMajorityService"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown:
> going to close listening sockets"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the global connection pool"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow
> Control ticket acquisitions."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.433+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all
> outstanding egress activity."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down free monitoring"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the HealthLog"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the TTL monitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring
> the global lock for shutdown"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache
> for shutdown"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down full-time data capture"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now
> exiting"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:01.434+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down","attr":{"exitCode":100}} archit@Archits-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongod
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.704+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling
> TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols
> 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.705+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire
> specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.706+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.706+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen in use."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.707+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during
> NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.708+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.708+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.708+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":38971,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Archits-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.708+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,
> "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName}
> unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.extfeatures"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.708+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.708+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.1.0"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.708+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.709+05:30"},"s":"E",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException
> in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data
> directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify
> another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by
> adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.709+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the
> ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MirrorMaestro"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the WaitForMajorityService"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown:
> going to close listening sockets"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the global connection pool"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow
> Control ticket acquisitions."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all
> outstanding egress activity."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down free monitoring"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the HealthLog"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the TTL monitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring
> the global lock for shutdown"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache
> for shutdown"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down full-time data capture"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now
> exiting"} {"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T23:24:25.710+05:30"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}

Comment: is it standalone node ? or replicaset ?
what does mongod.log show ?

Comment: This is standalone, I am trying to connect for development.

Comment: Logs: 

{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T07:17:18.451+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - shutting down with code 48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072651/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code-48)

Comment: @ArchitGarg  looks like your mongoDB database stopped. which is why you cant connect.

if you see "addr already in use" in mongod.log - this means the port 27017 is already used, and you should use a different port number

Comment: @Dror I have tried using another port but it is not working.

Comment: @Joe, tried and answers in link provided by you and it is not working for me.

Comment: @ArchitGarg   please include a larger portion of the mongod.log ,  from the time you try to start the service

Comment: That looks like a section of the Mongoose log, we'll need to see something from the mongod log to see why it isn't running.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I have updated the mongod log in question.

Answer (score 0):

The last edit (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70068861/5) is a mess, not a "full error".

There are two and a half logs.

The first part is half of the log with missing beginning. It says:

> "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":38271,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Archits-

followed by

> "msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}

Which mean :

- you didn't start it as `sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb/`
- something else is listening on 27017, likely mongod you started before that.

2 other logs start from `archit@Archits-MacBook-Pro ~ % mongod` followed by `"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Archits-` are identical and spell the same error:

> :{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}

which means `/data/db` does not exists or requires elevated privileges to access.

Considering the struggle, you may find it simpler to use pre-configured docker images https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the official MongoDB manual for [installation on Mac](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/),

try the following:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

If you are still not able to connect to MongoDB (maybe because there is some service already using the port 27017), try the above command after restarting your machine.