# MongoD failed to start in Arch based system

Tags: linux, mongodb, arch

Whenever I try to run mongoD it shows following output. I am in Garuda linux. Any idea what's happening here?

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.279+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically
> disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify
> --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.280+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire
> specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.280+05:45"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured
> during NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.280+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP
> FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set
> tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.281+05:45"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured
> during NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.282+05:45"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.282+05:45"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered
> PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.282+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading
> initialized"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.282+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB
> starting","attr":{"pid":4793,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"HP-Notebook"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.282+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build
> Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.5","gitVersion":"d65fd89df3fc039b5c55933c0f71d647a54510ae","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL
> 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.282+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating
> System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Garuda","version":"Soaring"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.282+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set
> by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"E",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error
> setting up
> listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address
> already in use"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",
> "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the
> ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MirrorMaestro"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the WaitForMajorityService"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the global connection pool"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",
> "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all
> outstanding egress activity."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down free monitoring"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the HealthLog"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down the TTL monitor"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.283+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring
> the global lock for shutdown"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.284+05:45"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",
> "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache
> for shutdown"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.284+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down full-time data capture"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.284+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now
> exiting"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-01-17T19:45:24.284+05:45"},"s":"I",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting
> down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}

Comment: I think you have the answer in the messages already: "msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}

Comment: What is the solution for this any idea? I am new to the database.

Comment: you need to  change the port to some not used yet maybe check here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975929/socketexception-address-already-in-use-mongodb/57076223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I looked the exit code 48 up and it means that there is something running on the same port; so either you kill the process that is running on this port or use another one.

There is a link to the post I found:
[MongoDB - shutting down with code 48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072651/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code-48)

It says that the default port is already in use (which is 27017); so either you kill this port by running: `npx kill-port 27017`

or you run it on a different port by adding the --port flag.

for example:  `sudo mongod --dbpath [thePathToYourFolder] --port 27018`

edit:

Also you'd need to provide the port that you're connecting to when you run mongosh:
`mongosh --port 27018`

Comment: Actually I had found the solution.But thank you for your efforts. I have marked this as a solution. I ran same commands as you have suggested here.