# exposing container ports for django application

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

My django application works fine when I run it locally but it doesn't work when I run it on a container.  Is it a port problem?  When I run it as a local application (without  docker) I point it to localhost:8000/polls and it works like a charm.  But I get **"The localhost page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"** when I run the container.  The application is pretty much verbatim from the Django tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

O/S Windows 10
Python 3.6
Docker 17.03.0-ce

UPDATED to include docker inspect output (the container ip address doesn't work either):

> C:\Users\jonathan>docker inspect xenodochial_swanson
>   [
>       {
>           "Id": "0394ca73fb06492031a43c3056bc26181a0a0d5f685b414f14775dfd506a7a3f",
>           "Created": "2017-03-21T03:27:42.432908Z",
>           "Path": "/bin/sh",
>           "Args": [
>               "-c",
>               "python /usr/src/toplevel/manage.py runserver"
>           ],
>           "State": {
>               "Status": "running",
>               "Running": true,
>               "Paused": false,
>               "Restarting": false,
>               "OOMKilled": false,
>               "Dead": false,
>               "Pid": 3415,
>               "ExitCode": 0,
>               "Error": "",
>               "StartedAt": "2017-03-21T03:27:42.933502Z",
>               "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
>           },
>           "Image": "sha256:18be11864bbd096c71343d6621712d2dfed06a3e0bef0d72bea3e3bd97d94509",
>           "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0394ca73fb06492031a43c3056bc26181a0a0d5f685b414f14775dfd506a7a3f/resolv.conf",
>           "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0394ca73fb06492031a43c3056bc26181a0a0d5f685b414f14775dfd506a7a3f/hostname",
>           "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0394ca73fb06492031a43c3056bc26181a0a0d5f685b414f14775dfd506a7a3f/hosts",
>           "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/0394ca73fb06492031a43c3056bc26181a0a0d5f685b414f14775dfd506a7a3f/0394ca73fb06492031a43c3056bc26181a0a0d5f685b414f14775dfd506a7a3f-json.log",
>           "Name": "/xenodochial_swanson",
>           "RestartCount": 0,
>           "Driver": "overlay2",
>           "MountLabel": "",
>           "ProcessLabel": "",
>           "AppArmorProfile": "",
>           "ExecIDs": [
>               "472a4b94af64b347ff34e6d98875bf16e183d04974d7497f7c6d68469398d70e"
>           ],
>           "HostConfig": {
>               "Binds": null,
>               "ContainerIDFile": "",
>               "LogConfig": {
>                   "Type": "json-file",
>                   "Config": {}
>               },
>               "NetworkMode": "default",
>               "PortBindings": {
>                   "8000/tcp": [
>                       {
>                           "HostIp": "",
>                           "HostPort": "8000"
>                       }
>                   ]
>               },
>               "RestartPolicy": {
>                   "Name": "no",
>                   "MaximumRetryCount": 0
>               },
>               "AutoRemove": false,
>               "VolumeDriver": "",
>               "VolumesFrom": null,
>               "CapAdd": null,
>               "CapDrop": null,
>               "Dns": [],
>               "DnsOptions": [],
>               "DnsSearch": [],
>               "ExtraHosts": null,
>               "GroupAdd": null,
>               "IpcMode": "",
>               "Cgroup": "",
>               "Links": null,
>               "OomScoreAdj": 0,
>               "PidMode": "",
>               "Privileged": false,
>               "PublishAllPorts": false,
>               "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
>               "SecurityOpt": null,
>               "UTSMode": "",
>               "UsernsMode": "",
>               "ShmSize": 67108864,
>               "Runtime": "runc",
>               "ConsoleSize": [
>                   30,
>                   120
>               ],
>               "Isolation": "",
>               "CpuShares": 0,
>               "Memory": 0,
>               "NanoCpus": 0,
>               "CgroupParent": "",
>               "BlkioWeight": 0,
>               "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
>               "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
>               "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
>               "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
>               "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
>               "CpuPeriod": 0,
>               "CpuQuota": 0,
>               "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
>               "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
>               "CpusetCpus": "",
>               "CpusetMems": "",
>               "Devices": [],
>               "DiskQuota": 0,
>               "KernelMemory": 0,
>               "MemoryReservation": 0,
>               "MemorySwap": 0,
>               "MemorySwappiness": -1,
>               "OomKillDisable": false,
>               "PidsLimit": 0,
>               "Ulimits": null,
>               "CpuCount": 0,
>               "CpuPercent": 0,
>               "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
>               "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
>           },
>           "GraphDriver": {
>               "Name": "overlay2",
>               "Data": {
>                   "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/61d1577ad2925d86ae68c5bb2140aa7b85f4d2849866a4875a8a50f35726c7af-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/70d4d830664d3a9da7f1c4061421924fb27c547e771292961296b6f068549d94/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/efcad5a908608693833608bb6874cd198c625e9f7dbef72a3a2165fea42c4189/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8553d226e111b5d9837656d1bfef7c6e4aa7a02280d154824db3b05dded594d9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/de3b36b0203b5d17ecd88106a54ae87fe49d88fb1bec04cf5641c1a9d92051fd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9ff4cd59d0321627d952a01c2e97f09e9b0cee6b58b69ac1ef89ce1012fc3ca0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/52161c423deed2bc1a58fbb5252332c0bf68ebe4f8843ded1679f1599d9a09b6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ccf0d30cc04d29769faaaf0d3abc4c822ddea6caa62ff21a67629b74fdf5ccea/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9213e08c956581cdca5f99efa2632dfb1c2eb86684f7d0b4138c86a8121f43ca/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eca56289a13e584416695b55c77907dbe40e24e726d672f5a5cf40be95521b27/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/52b015f1e0d4bf4b00ec4336091f8bc6c49c1407c6f270e56aa5c2931dd18994/diff",
>                   "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/61d1577ad2925d86ae68c5bb2140aa7b85f4d2849866a4875a8a50f35726c7af/merged",
>                   "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/61d1577ad2925d86ae68c5bb2140aa7b85f4d2849866a4875a8a50f35726c7af/diff",
>                   "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/61d1577ad2925d86ae68c5bb2140aa7b85f4d2849866a4875a8a50f35726c7af/work"
>               }
>           },
>           "Mounts": [],
>           "Config": {
>               "Hostname": "0394ca73fb06",
>               "Domainname": "",
>               "User": "",
>               "AttachStdin": false,
>               "AttachStdout": true,
>               "AttachStderr": true,
>               "ExposedPorts": {
>                   "8000/tcp": {}
>               },
>               "Tty": true,
>               "OpenStdin": false,
>               "StdinOnce": false,
>               "Env": [
>                   "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
>                   "LANG=C.UTF-8",
>                   "GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D",
>                   "PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.0",
>                   "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=9.0.1"
>               ],
>               "Cmd": [
>                   "/bin/sh",
>                   "-c",
>                   "python /usr/src/toplevel/manage.py runserver"
>               ],
>               "ArgsEscaped": true,
>               "Image": "django-polls:latest",
>               "Volumes": null,
>               "WorkingDir": "",
>               "Entrypoint": null,
>               "OnBuild": null,
>               "Labels": {}
>           },
>           "NetworkSettings": {
>               "Bridge": "",
>               "SandboxID": "ab70160de420857c339a85aeb99a72533b2fd382606e08e39921dc3efcece6da",
>               "HairpinMode": false,
>               "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
>               "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>               "Ports": {
>                   "8000/tcp": [
>                       {
>                           "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
>                           "HostPort": "8000"
>                       }
>                   ]
>               },
>               "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ab70160de420",
>               "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
>               "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
>               "EndpointID": "e52b41debee6e478c638440cdf930c1a63f7a2c5a588010cd0f47fb1eea47b05",
>               "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
>               "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
>               "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>               "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
>               "IPPrefixLen": 16,
>               "IPv6Gateway": "",
>               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
>               "Networks": {
>                   "bridge": {
>                       "IPAMConfig": null,
>                       "Links": null,
>                       "Aliases": null,
>                       "NetworkID": "d494fc6cb4c7c4af4bb936d8a89087bce1883e64cfad5c34c52775125dc13555",
>                       "EndpointID": "e52b41debee6e478c638440cdf930c1a63f7a2c5a588010cd0f47fb1eea47b05",
>                       "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
>                       "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
>                       "IPPrefixLen": 16,
>                       "IPv6Gateway": "",
>                       "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
>                       "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>                       "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   ]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
EXPOSE 8000
COPY ./ /usr/src/
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/requirements.txt
RUN pip install /usr/src/django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
CMD python /usr/src/toplevel/manage.py runserver
```

Running the Container (no visible problems):

```
C:\temp\djangopoc>docker run -p 8000:8000 -t django-polls
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 21, 2017 - 01:05:05
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Troubleshooting info? (notice the port says 0.0.0.0:8000) problem?:

```
C:\temp\djangopoc>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d28b7c336664        django-polls        "/bin/sh -c 'pytho..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   xenodochial_boyd
```

In case it's helpful to diagnose, Build Instructions and output:

```
C:\temp\djangopoc>docker build -t django-polls:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.948 MB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.6
3.6: Pulling from library/python
Digest: sha256:438208801c4801efbf8b0e318ff6548460b27bd1fbcb7bb188273d13871ab43f
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.6
 ---> a1782fa44ef7
Step 2/6 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in cde33b9d347d
 ---> 34ebaa1cfd3c
Removing intermediate container cde33b9d347d
Step 3/6 : COPY ./ /usr/src/
 ---> a6b591e2fd0b
Removing intermediate container e45a71d06c9a
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install -r /usr/src/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 9d995a9129fb
Collecting appdirs==1.4.2 (from -r /usr/src/requirements.txt (line 1))
...
Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas==0.19.2->-r /usr/src/requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading numpy-1.12.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (16.8MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyramid==1.8.2->-r /usr/src/requirements.txt (line 28))
Installing collected packages: appdirs, six, python-dateutil, arrow, docutils, colorama, PyYAML, jmespath, botocore, s3transfer, pyasn1, rsa, awscli, chardet, binaryornot, click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, jinja2-time, whichcraft, poyo, future, cookiecutter, decorator, Django, funcsigs, hupper, mysql-connector, pyparsing, packaging, pytz, numpy, pandas, PasteDeploy, zope.deprecation, translationstring, WebOb, venusian, zope.interface, repoze.lru, pyramid
  Running setup.py install for arrow: started
    Running setup.py install for arrow: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for PyYAML: started
    Running setup.py install for PyYAML: finished with status 'done'
...
  Running setup.py install for repoze.lru: started
    Running setup.py install for repoze.lru: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed Django-1.10.6 Jinja2-2.9.5 MarkupSafe-0.23 PasteDeploy-1.5.2 PyYAML-3.12 WebOb-1.7.1 appdirs-1.4.2 arrow-0.10.0 awscli-1.11.55 binaryornot-0.4.0 botocore-1.5.18 chardet-2.3.0 click-6.7 colorama-0.3.7 cookiecutter-1.5.1 decorator-4.0.11 docutils-0.13.1 funcsigs-1.0.2 future-0.16.0 hupper-0.4.2 jinja2-time-0.2.0 jmespath-0.9.1 mysql-connector-2.1.4 numpy-1.12.1 packaging-16.8 pandas-0.19.2 poyo-0.4.0 pyasn1-0.2.3 pyparsing-2.1.10 pyramid-1.8.2 python-dateutil-2.6.0 pytz-2016.10 repoze.lru-0.6 rsa-3.4.2 s3transfer-0.1.10 six-1.10.0 translationstring-1.3 venusian-1.0 whichcraft-0.4.0 zope.deprecation-4.2.0 zope.interface-4.3.3
 ---> dbc28b5002d5
Removing intermediate container 9d995a9129fb
Step 5/6 : RUN pip install /usr/src/django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
 ---> Running in 27d40c4a746a
Processing /usr/src/django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: django-polls
  Running setup.py install for django-polls: started
    Running setup.py install for django-polls: finished with status 'done'    
Successfully installed django-polls-0.1
 ---> 1771f5ff2479
Removing intermediate container 27d40c4a746a
Step 6/6 : CMD python /usr/src/toplevel/manage.py runserver
 ---> Running in d754737737ec
 ---> 18be11864bbd
Removing intermediate container d754737737ec
Successfully built 18be11864bbd
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a
 non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context
 will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and
 reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Comment: i guess your container must be using docker machine which has different ip, try to check using `docker-machine ip default`, where `default` is docker-machine name

Comment: Try opening your Preferred browser with 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: tried 0.0.0.0:8000 and it didn't work.  also tried docker-machine ip [default] .  pretty much anything I type there (machine  name, ip address, 0:0:0:0, 128.0.0.1) all says "Host does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

When running application on docker machine you should be using docker-machine ip instead of `localhost`

use : `docker-machine ip default` to get docker machine ip, where `default` is your machine

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing with this command, but I tried it and it got an error.  I tried this for 0.0.0.0 and 128.0.0.1  Same error C:\temp\djangopoc>docker-machine ip 192.168.1.90
    Host does not exist: "192.168.1.90".

Comment: if you are running `docker run -p 8000:8000 -t django-polls`, then use `192.168.1.90:8000`

Comment: `docker-machine ls` should list the docker machines

Comment: when I type that  it would appear as though  I  don't  have any machines?   Nothing is returned.  C:\temp\djangopoc>docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS

Comment: i guess you don't have any machine created on your system, check more on docker machine

Comment: check this https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#environment-variables-and-default-values

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the logs inside of the container running your django application? To get into the container use `docker exec -it django-polls bash`.

Comment: Tried it and got this feedback:  C:\temp\djangopoc>docker exec -it django-polls bash
Error response from daemon: No such container: django-polls

Comment: Did you do it when your container was running? Whatever your image name is when you run `docker ps` is what you should use in place of `django-polls`

Comment: ah, got it.  I'm in the shell.  The app doesn't do any logging, but I executed the test algorithms from the shell and it passed all of the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use the following command:

```
CMD python /usr/src/toplevel/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

[【ref1】What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)