# How to run Python server on Docker's container

Tags: python, bash, docker, simplehttpserver

I want to run Python HTTP server on docker container.

My `DockerFile` looks like this:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:latest

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install linux-headers-amd64 build-essential libc-dev gcc

RUN conda install --yes gcc
RUN conda install --yes numpy
RUN conda install --yes scipy
RUN conda install --yes gensim
RUN pip install annoy

RUN conda config --add channels conda-forge
RUN conda install --yes spacy

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD my-app.tar /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/source
```

I build the image with:

```
docker build -t my-app-poc .
```

Start the container and enter command:

```
docker run -i -t -p 9998:9998
```

In the Docker image's bash I run the script:

```
python Service.py
```

Which starts correctly:

```
Wed Apr  5 13:09:51 2017 Server Starts - :9998
```

But when I enter the address on my host:

```
http://localhost:9998
```

Nothing happens. I've tried also put `EXPOSE 9998` at the end of my `DockerFile` but it wasn't help.

If I enter `docker-machine` address on my host:

```
http://192.168.99.100:9989/
```

it works. But I want to run that image on regular server, not my local machine - so everything should be exposed to localhost.

I tried it on Windows 7.

Do you have any idea how to run this?

I will be very glad for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not be related, but I cannot add a comment, so a standalone reply you get!

In the Docker container you may have to bind your application to the `0.0.0.0` host. [See this link.](http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html)

It seems to me (though I would have to know more about the app to be certain) that you are looking for a connection on the loop-back interface. This exposes the listener to the local machine only. By contrast, `0.0.0.0` serves to expose the listener to all network interfaces on the machine. Specifially in this case, the docker network adapter. For a more detailed explanation, [see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

What you described is a normal behavior. Docker images are running in a virtualized environment, therefore cannot share the loopback address. What you need to do is to redirect the traffic from your server to your docker image.

[This documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) should have all the answers you need.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

The -p expose option can also take an ip address. If you want to also bind to 127.0.0.1 instead, it goes there.

try something like: `-p 127.0.0.1:9998:9998`

Answer (score 0):

John Patterson's answer basically nailed it, let me add some more things that wouldn't fit in a comment.

If you want to see the logs of your HTTP server (and you should), then add the following to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

because by default everything printed to `stdout` by Python will go into a buffer and you wouldn't see the server's output with `docker logs` unless a considerable amount has already been written.

Also note that `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile brings precious little. According to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
> functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
> image and the person who runs the container

which is not much. However, the `-P` flag of `docker run` maps all `EXPOSE`-d ports to some random high-order ports. The best way IMO to specify the port mappings using `-p` (lowercase).