# REST service deployed in Apache ServiceMix not accessible remotely

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am deploying an angular2 webapp in servicemix as a war file. This makes the app run on `localhost:8181/angular2webapp` url. I have a bundle installed for REST requests, which is basically a camel component.

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:9090"
serviceClass="com.mypackage.class.MyClass" />
```

Now this is a different origin request which I have configured to be allowed. All this setup is working fine on a single machine(Machine1). When I am trying to access `x.x.x.x:8181/angular2webapp`from a different machine(Machine2) in the same network, it is opening the basic page but when I call click a button which calls a REST endpoint of `com.mypackage.class.MyClass` in order to fill a table, I can see in browser console of Machine2 `GET http://localhost:9090/deviceservice/devices net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I hosted the cxf server on `x.x.x.x` as

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://x.x.x.x:9090"
serviceClass="com.mypackage.class.MyClass" />
```

and changed angular2 code to call 'x.x.x.x:9090 but it didnt work too. Moreover, I can call the REST service from postman as `GET` on `http://localhost:9090...` but not as `x.x.x.x:9090...`.

OR IS THE RIGHT QUESTION:

Is there a way to expose the REST server from ServiceMix outside?
If not, should I use something like NGINIX as a proxy server so that it everything happens with `localhost`?
What is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost in the address

```
address="http://0.0.0.0:9090"
```

You can likely find questions on SO about the difference between localhost/127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 etc such as: [What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Comment: Thanks it worked :) Could you also tell me the difference between a server created with cxf:rsServer and cxf:cxfEndpoint? Like it is done in this page: https://github.com/apache/servicemix/blob/master/examples/camel/camel-cxf-soap/camel-cxf-soap-route/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml

Comment: Also, I am putting in the IP in angular2 code. Is this a wrong way of doing different origin request? Should I have a proxy server or accept requests? Can you recommend a better way?

Comment: This seems not work with https , the netstat command tell me it listen on 127.0.0.1