# How to reach a linked service in docker-compose?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, netcat

According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links, if I specify the name of another service under `links` in `docker-compose`, I should be able to reach that service at a hostname identical to the service name.

To test this, I tried the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  tor:
    build: ./tor

  use_tor:
    build: ./use_tor
    links:
      - tor
```

where the `tor` and `use_tor` directories contain `Dockerfile`s:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── tor
│   └── Dockerfile
└── use_tor
    └── Dockerfile
```

which are, for `tor`:

```
FROM alpine:latest
EXPOSE 9050
RUN apk --update add tor
CMD ["tor"]
```

and for `use_tor`:

```
FROM alpine:latest
CMD ["nc", "-z", "tor", "9050"]
```

However, if I do `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`, I see from the logs that the `use_tor` service exits with status code 1:

```
Starting scrapercompose_tor_1
Recreating scrapercompose_use_tor_1
Attaching to scrapercompose_tor_1, scrapercompose_use_tor_1
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.123 [notice] Tor v0.2.8.12 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL LibreSSL 2.4.4 and Zlib 1.2.8.
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.123 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.123 [notice] Configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.129 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.000 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.000 [notice] We were built to run on a 64-bit CPU, with OpenSSL 1.0.1 or later, but with a version of OpenSSL that apparently lacks accelerated support for the NIST P-224 and P-256 groups. Building openssl with such support (using the enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 option when configuring it) would make ECDH much faster.
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
scrapercompose_use_tor_1 exited with code 1
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:36.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
tor_1      | May 02 15:36:36.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

Apparently the command `nc -z tor 9050` doesn't return the expected status code `0` on the `use_tor` container. However, it would seem to me that this should work. For example, if I modify the `tor` service to map port `9050` on the container to the host as follows,

```
services:
  tor:
    build: ./tor
    ports:
      - "9050:9050"
```

Then in my ordinary terminal, I do see that `nc -z localhost 9050` yields an exit code of `0`:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ nc -z localhost 9050
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ echo $?
0
```

In short, I would expect the hostname `tor` to behave like `localhost` on my the host after the port mapping, but this appears not to be the case. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question made me gawk at it for once. Although I cloned this example but was not able to get the solution. According to docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

> The `EXPOSE` instruction informs Docker that the **container listens on
>   the specified network ports at runtime. EXPOSE does not make the ports
>   of the container accessible to the host**. To do that, **you must use 
>   either the -p flag to publish a range of ports or the -P flag to 
>   publish all of the exposed ports**. You can expose one port number and 
>   publish it externally under another number.

So I think that may be because the tor service is running on 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 (for difference between them you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost))

> tor_1      | May 02 15:36:34.129 [notice] Opening Socks listener on
>   127.0.0.1:9050

It is accessible through terminal is because of the `ports` argument in `docker-compose.yml`  which does the same as `-p` argument.

All in all if the tor service listens on `0.0.0.0` then it should work as expected.

Comment: Though its a guess for now but I'll look through it tomorrow. Its night here in India.!! :D

Comment: Also I use the docker links same way that you've used and they work absolutely fine.!

Comment: This was exactly right. I fixed the problem by adding a configuration file `torrc` to the `tor` directory with the single line `SocksListenAddress 0.0.0.0` (cf. https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en), and added `COPY torrc /etc/tor/torrc` to the `Dockerfile`. Now I see `scrapercompose_use_tor_1 exited with code 0` in the docker-compose logs as expected.