# Why inet_ntoa returns 0.0.0.0 in this code?

Tags: c, structure, memcpy

This is the code I'm trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    uint8_t dip[4]={127,0,0,1};
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = 5000;
    memcpy(&serv_addr, dip, 4);
    printf("IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr));

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the final result on my terminal

```
IP: 0.0.0.0
```

I don't understand why I obtained that result. Does anyone know what it's happening?

Comment: Did you mean `memcpy(&(serv_addr.sin_addr), dip, 4);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Comment: Ouch... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
  memcpy(&serv_addr, dip, 4);
```

where you forgot to mention the target member (as nested `struct in_addr`), you used the structure variable address instead. Do it like

```
 memcpy(&(serv_addr.sin_addr), dip, 4);
```

and it should work.