# Unable to access jekyll blog from browser hosted on google cloud

Tags: networking, cloud, jekyll, google-compute-engine, firewall

These are my firewall rules on google compute instance.
I am running a jekyll blog on the machine at port 4001.
But I am unable to access the blog on `http://mach-ip:4001`

I have been trying since last night. I am wondering, what's wrong. Same firewall rules on Amazon EC2, doesn't cause any problems.

which rule should I edit? Or if there is any other thing that i am missing?
Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start jekyll server like this

```
jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4567
```

not like this

```
jekyll serve --port 4567
```

to listen on every available network interface
For an explaination, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)