# Server not binding to port within docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a one-machine swarm (i.e. one master node, that's it), which has the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: rbalicki/hellorocket:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://docker:docker@db:5432/pw_back
    command: cargo run # this runs the server
  db:
    image: rbalicki/pg:latest
```

I run the following commands, per the tutorial:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1
docker-machine ssh myvm1 "docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.100:2377"
docker-machine scp docker-compose.yml myvm1:~
docker-machine ssh myvm1 "docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml hellorocketstack"
```

`docker machine ls` gives me an IP of `tcp://192.168.99.100:2376`.

The Dockerfile for the `web` process definitely exposes 8000, as well. Locally, when I run this server, it connects to port 8000 with no problems. However, within the vm, it doesn't receive any requests when I curl `192.168.99.100:8001` (likewise for `8000`). This is true, even if I kill the vm and completely restart my machine.

However, if I install other services (e.g. visualizer, from the tutorial), they work just fine.

This is driving me crazy! How can I figure out what is going on?

Also, within the vm, I also cannot call `curl localhost:8001` (which works for visualizer, at the remapped port). Any help is appreciated! Are there next steps I can take to debug this?

Edit: `nc -zv 192.168.99.100 8001` also turns up nothing! (It works for visualizer)

Edit2: `docker inspect CONTAINER` shows:

```
     "Config": {
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8001/tcp": {}
        },
     },
     "NetworkSettings": {
        "Ports": {
            "8001/tcp": null
        },
     }
```

Which is the same thing as the `docker inspect` command shows for the working example (modulo exposed port number)

Comment: What do the logs for the web container show? If you connect to the web container with a `docker exec` can you `curl http://localhost:8000`?

Comment: That worked - I got a response from the server. What now?

Comment: Stop the docker service and run `iptables -S` and post the rules. Check if `ufw` or `selinux` or `firewalld` is enabled on your VM. Some VMs by default  has IPTables rules to allow 22 port only

Comment: Ok, `iptables -S` on the vm gives me https://gist.github.com/rbalicki2/0642dfac22d0ce57616a8f4381664a27 . The root installation is debian, so I don't think it has an `selinux` firewall but /shrug. `firewall-cmd` and `ufw` are both not found.

Comment: The network settings in the oracle VM are: Adapter 1, NAT, Cable Connected, Deny Promiscuous Mode, Port forwarding: SSH, localhost:49539 -> 22; Adapter 2: Host-only Adapter, Name: vboxnet0, Deny Promiscuous Mode; the port forwarding settings button is disabled

Comment: Update: if I run the service (after removing the dependency on the db) by itself, in the VM, using `docker run -p 4000:8000 rbalicki/hellorocket:latest cargo run`, when I `curl localhost:4000` I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused` and no indication in the server logs that a connection was made.

Comment: Update: If I run it in the VM as above, but specify `--network=host`, it works! This does not work when running it outside of the VM, whether in swarm mode or not. It does not appear to be accessible at the IP I would expect outside the VM, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that rocket was listening on `localhost` and not `0.0.0.0`. Setting the environment variable `ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0` fixed things.

In the Docker tutorial example python server, changing `0.0.0.0` to `localhost` also broke things in exactly the same way.

[What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)