# Akka, sending Udp fails with "Can't assign requested address"

Tags: macos, sockets, udp, akka

Trying to [Bind (and Send) as in the docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/io-udp.html#bind-and-send-) but it fails:

> [akka://udp-test/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/0] Successfully bound to [/127.0.0.1:64387]
> Sending msg: bla
> [akka://udp-test/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/0] Can't assign requested address
> [akka://udp-test/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/0] Closing DatagramChannel after being stopped

**Fails as above** if the target address is a public ip like `62.138.0.158` or in the local network like `192.168.2.3`, both of which respond to `ping`.

**Succeeds** if the target address is `127.0.0.1` (localhost) on any port.

**Succeeds** after changing the local address to my current ip in the local network (e.g.: `192.168.2.2`)

**Fails differently** for an invalid ip

> [akka://default/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/1] Name resolution failed for remote address [invalid-ip:6969]

**Succeeds** if I do exactly as [Simple Send in the docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/io-udp.html) instead. I.e., with the `Bind` replaced by `SimpleSender`. But I also need to listen in the same port and I expected it to work as the doc for [Bind (and Send)](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/io-udp.html#bind-and-send-) says:

> Sending datagrams is achieved by using the Send message

---

**To reproduce:**

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.{IO, Udp}
import akka.io.Udp.Send
import akka.util.ByteString

object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("udp-test")

  val destAddr = new InetSocketAddress("62.138.0.158", 6969)
  private val props = Props(classOf[Listener], destAddr)
  val udp: ActorRef = system.actorOf(props, "udp-actor")

  Thread.sleep(500) //give time for the actor to be created
  udp ! "bla"

}

class Listener(remote: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor {
  import context.system
  IO(Udp) ! Udp.Bind(self, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 0))

  def receive = {
    case Udp.Bound(local) =>
      context.become(ready(sender()))
    case other =>
      println(s"Received something else: $other")
  }

  def ready(socket: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      println(s"Sending msg: $msg")
      socket ! Send(ByteString(msg), remote)
    case other =>
      println(s"Received something else: $other")
  }
}
```

---

I'm running on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after setting the local address to `0.0.0.0`, meaning "[listen on every available network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)".

I had two network interfaces, each with an IP address:

- `127.0.0.1` on the loopback interface
- a `192.168.x.x` in the local network, talking to a router.

By binding specifically to `127.0.0.1` I wouldn't get packets coming from the outside, addressed to my `192.168.x.x` IP. So listening to "all of them" makes sense.

My code works fine now but I still don't get why this error occurred when *sending*.