# google compute platform firewall rules

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, firewall, iptables, portforwarding

I have already opened the ports but its still not working.

From gcloud on my local machine:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute firewall-rules list
To show all fields of the firewall, please show in JSON format: --format=json
To show all fields in table format, please see the examples in --help.

NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                             DENY
default-allow-https     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22
django                  default  EGRESS     1000      tcp:8000,tcp:80,tcp:8080,tcp:443
django-in               default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:8000,tcp:80,tcp:8080,tcp:443
```

From the instance on google cloud:

```
admin-u5214628@instance-1:~$ wget localhost:8080
--2017-11-22 01:23:56--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 FOUND
Location: http://localhost:8080/login/?next=/ [following]
--2017-11-22 01:23:56--  http://localhost:8080/login/?next=/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html              [ <=>                ]   6.26K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2017-11-22 01:23:56 (161 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [6411]
```

But via the external ip, nothing is shown:

```
http://35.197.1.158:8080/
```

---

I checked the port by the following command:

```
root@instance-1:/etc# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1539/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2138/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1735/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1735/sshd
```

I'm not sure if this is enough for the Ubuntu firewall setting? looks ok to me.

And on the instance, I checked everything I can think of.

[image]

And the UFW (uncomplicated firewall):

```
root@instance-1:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

From my understanding, this means it is off, so not blocking anything.

---

As suggested, I try to configure `iptables`:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
```

Then I save it:

```
root@instance-1:~# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Nov 23 00:16:44 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [175:18493]
:INPUT ACCEPT [175:18493]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [154:15965]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [154:15965]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 23 00:16:44 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Nov 23 00:16:44 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:300]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6:300]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:360]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [6:360]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 23 00:16:44 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Nov 23 00:16:44 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [169:18193]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [163:17013]
[6:300] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 23 00:16:44 2017
```

It looks like this now:

```
root@instance-1:~# iptables -v -n -x -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 80 packets, 5855 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 52 packets, 6047 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

To make sure the rules are applied and live:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
iptables-apply /etc/iptables.rules
```

I don't think I need to restart/reset the instance.

---

I think I need to [forward traffic to local ip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751467/forward-port-to-local-ip-port):

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
# python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 24, 2017 - 17:54:00
Django version 1.8.18, using settings 'codebench.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

This way did not work...

---

Tried:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 &
```

This definitely worked on my local machine, just not on the google instance, I'm so puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when I create an instance of a compute engine, I should explicitly flag that HTTP(S) access is allowed. That may be one thing to have a look at.

Another one - the OS you deploy/use in the compute engine instance might have its own firewall rules. They need to be amended accordingly.

Based on newly provided information about UFW and Ubuntu. I am not very confident with Ubuntu, but I understand that UFW is a wrapper around iptables. I may be wrong, but I guess it may be better if it is enabled. Then you might be able to get more details about the firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the server only listening to 127.0.0.1:8080 not 0.0.0.0:8080, as it should be. That's the reason you are getting a reply with http://localhost:8080/ not
with http://35.197.1.158:8080 For more details checkout this answer from stackoverflow [What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

To change configuration for Apache to listen to 0.0.0.0:8080 or to a specific IP and port follow this document https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: haven't installed any proper server on that vm, like Apache, it was run with `runserver`, this problem was a long time ago, now the app is set up with a private server (with Nginx)