# Can't access jupyter notebook in local vagrant virtualbox via local browser

Tags: vagrant, ipython, jupyter

As the title described. I already set the Vagrantfile with:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888, auto_correct: true
```

and also set the jupyter_notebook_config.py as:

```
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

When I activate the notebook in vagrant virtualbox the displayed info was normal:

[image]

But local browser (Safari) can't access to it by any means.

[image]

Comment: This might be a better question for serverfault.com

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled on a issue that seems similar. Here is what solved it for me:

- In the Vagrantfile, I added:

  `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"`
- From the vagrant virtual machine start jupyter notebook with:

  `jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip 0.0.0.0`
- Or in the browser of the host access jupyter via *192.168.33.10:8888*

Comment: Thank you! I am running Ubuntu server in a local virtual box vm, and the " jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip 0.0.0.0" worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that the server is listening on localhost in the VM so it is only available within the VM.

If you want the server to be available from your host, you should bind the ip to `0.0.0.0`

see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/4296747) to understand the differences

Adding the following in your config will do the trick

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
```