# Docker Compose port mapping: 127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I am currently working with Docker and a simple Flask website to which I want to send images. For this I'm working on port 8080, but the mapping from docker to host is not working properly as I am unable to connect. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  dev:
    container_name: xvision-dev
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/dev.dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /path/to/images:/app/images
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
      - "8080"
      - "8080:8080"
```

dev.dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt update && apt install -y python-tk

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

app.py

```
@APP.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"
def main():
    """Start the script"""
    APP.json_encoder = Float32Encoder
    APP.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=os.getenv('PORT', 8080))
```

I start my docker with `docker-compose up`, this gives the output: `Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`.

But when I do a get request to 127.0.0.1:8080/test I get that there is no response.

I have also tried `docker-compose run --service-port dev` as some people have suggested online but this says that there is no service dev.

Can someone help me for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not that experienced in python or flask but it seems like your server never starts as you're never calling `main`.

Comment: The server is starting as based on the output provided, the code included seems incomplete though.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
APP.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=os.getenv('PORT', 8080))
```

Using only:

```
ports:

  - "8080:8080"
```

is enough

Comment: And still use docker-compose up to start the docker?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost#20778887) for `0.0.0.0` vs `127.0.0.1`