# Can not connect to localhost by Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using **Volley:1.1.1** to connect to localhost in my android application

my code :

```
public static final String API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5365/api/Account/LoginUser?username=A_easy&password=123";

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("APIRes", "response : " + response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("APIRes", "error : " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);
```

The error I get is  **error:null**

The Logcat is showing this

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 170 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/APIRes: error : null
```

-It works on **Postman**

-I have tried **GET** method but the result is the same

-I have tried `10.0.2.2` and my **IP address** but the result is the same

Comment: Have you added the internet permission?

Comment: @SushobhNadiger Yes I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: You are running a service in your local computer and trying to access the service from android device/emulator right?

Comment: @salmanwahed Yes

Answer (score 1):

Run your service in `0.0.0.0`. It will make the server available in the same network. So if your computer's IP is `192.168.X.Y` then you can access the service in:

```
http://192.168.X.Y:5365/api/Account/LoginUser?username=A_easy&password=123
```

Form more information I am Quoting from a [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost):

> 127.0.0.1 is normally the IP address assigned to the "loopback" or local-only interface. This is a "fake" network adapter that can only
>   communicate within the same host. It's often used when you want a
>   network-capable application to only serve clients on the same host. A
>   process that is listening on 127.0.0.1 for connections will only
>   receive local connections on that socket.
>
> "localhost" is normally the hostname for the 127.0.0.1 IP address.
>   It's usually set in /etc/hosts (or the Windows equivalent named
>   "hosts" somewhere under %WINDIR%). You can use it just like any other
>   hostname - try "ping localhost" to see how it resolves to 127.0.0.1.
>
> 0.0.0.0 has a couple of different meanings, but in this context, when a server is told to listen on 0.0.0.0 that means "listen on every
>   available network interface". The loopback adapter with IP address
>   127.0.0.1 from the perspective of the server process looks just like any other network adapter on the machine, so a server told to listen
>   on 0.0.0.0 will accept connections on that interface too.

Comment: What do you mean by Run your service in `0.0.0.0`
how should I do it?

Comment: Your computer's IP address is: `10.0.2.2` right? You need to access `http://10.0.2.2:5365/api/Account/LoginUser?username=A_easy&password=123` from your android. You need to bind the server address to your IP address.