# Create multiple IP for one interface and be able to run a service on each IP on a specific port

Tags: python

We have a requirement that we need to run a service for N different IPs on a same port but have only one network interface.

Is the same possible in Python - I do not have any code to share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't really anything to do with Python, most operating systems allow you to associate multiple IP addresses with the same adapter.  see [here](https://serverfault.com/q/748005) for some ways to do this under Linux

in Python you'd just bind to `0.0.0.0` (and/or `::` for IPv6) and, assuming you'd set things up elsewhere appropriately, it should just work

Comment: What IP address is 0.0.0.0 and what needs to be setup?

Comment: I assumed you knew how networking/sockets work!  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/1358308 for a primer.  there are lots of tutorials/blog articles about this