# Is it possible to remotely track the GUI of chromium when running in headless mode?

Tags: node.js, linux, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, chrome-remote-debugging

I'm running puppeteer on AWS EC2 AMI (Linux) in headless mode to do some web scraping. Is it possible to track the GUI of it remotely, maybe from my local Windows setup?

I referred to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) article and was wondering if adding `--remote-debugging-port=9222` to my code and then visiting `http://localhost:9222` on a local browser would let me see the GUI. Is it possible to do this? I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. You have to set the `--remote-debugging-address` argument.

Quote from the [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#remote-debugging-address):

> Use the given address instead of the default loopback for accepting remote debugging connections. Should be used together with --remote-debugging-port. Note that the remote debugging protocol does not perform any authentication, so exposing it too widely can be a security risk.

**Explanation**

By default, Chrome binds to `127.0.0.1` (the local-only interface), which only allows connections from the machine itself. If you set the argument to `0.0.0.0` Chrome listens to all network interfaces allowing connections from outside of the machine (check out [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/5627599) for more information). However, you still need to make sure there are no firewalls in place that might block connections, but by default that should not be the case.

That means, starting Chrome like this will allow debugging from another computer:

```
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 [possible other flags]
```

You could now visit `http://IP_OF_YOUR_MACHINE:9222` and would be confronted with the DevTools GUI of Chrome. Alternatively, you could connect to the machine using [`puppeteer.connect`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions):

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserURL: 'http://...:9222' });
// ...
```

**Security Considerations**

Keep in mind that this port is exposed to *anyone* with access to the Internet. You might want to consider using a Firewall to block connections or use a library like [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy) to filter any connections before passing them on to your browser.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Although `--remote-debugging-address` binds to all interfaces, making it possible to connect from outside "localhost", chrome doesn't allow the debugging interface outside the machine that the browser process is running with the following error "Host header is specified and is not an IP address or localhost.".