# How to run cURL inside Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use Gitlab CI to build a docker Nginx image then run & test a container by calling cURL on that container's Domain:PORT like this:

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: docker_curl_sandbox_img
  CONTAINER_NAME: docker_curl_sandbox_cont

image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

build_docker_img:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .

test_run_docker:
  stage: test
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
  script:
    - docker kill $CONTAINER_NAME || true
    - docker rm $CONTAINER_NAME || true
    - docker run -p 8087:80 --name $CONTAINER_NAME -d $IMAGE_NAME
    - sleep 25
    - docker ps
    - cat /etc/hosts
    - curl http://docker:8087
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./src /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I have tried:
`curl http://docker:8087`,
`curl http://0.0.0.0:8087`,
`curl http://localhost:8087`,
... I have tried the domains from `/etc/hosts` with no luck:

[image]

but I am keep getting: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8087: Connection refused`

[image]

any idea? thanks

---

**Update:** adding results of `docker ps` and `netstat -na`:

[image]

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: @Simoyw I used docker-compose then I curl using the service name I gave it in the docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

(edited)

URL `http://0.0.0.0:8087` is invalid, that's why the connection is refused. See [What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Use `netstat -na|grep 8087` on the docker host to check where/if the nginx connection is listening.

To access a different, non linked container you need to route through the port forwarding: try accessing it with the docker host external address (ie: `curl http://192.168.1.2:8087`).

Comment: Hello @Iron, the curl is installed inside the docker which enough I think, but you are right with the PORT, nginx is not connected. Please have a look at my update. thanks.

Comment: Indeed you are running curl inside a docker, but not the image you are building, and that's fine. Since you are inside another container, netstat doesnt show anything. They aren't linked too, so you can't use local addressing. Try using the external IP address to connect, like `curl http://192.168.1.2:8087`.