# how can I get common dev ports like 5000 and 8000 to work with tailscale?

Tags: ssh, server, raspberry-pi, port, vpn

I have tailscale up and running on the raspberry pi.  Its incredibly easy to use and SSH with.

Just having one problem now, the IP address that it assigns me doesn't share the results of localhost:5000 or localhost:8000 with the other computers on my new tailscale local-type network.  However, it shares localhost:80 just fine and of course :22 and the VNC port I guess.

Those pretty common ports for development, and I'm not really versed opening/forwarding/closing ports, which is the whole reason I'm using tailscale.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to get these ports to work on my other connected machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, I was lacking a fundamental understanding of networking.  There was nothing for me to change with tailscale or zerotier (or ports/nmap, router, ISP etc).

I had to serve my content on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.

This helped me out:
[What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)