# How to host NextJS app on 0.0.0.0:3000 with nrwl/next (not localhost:3000)

Tags: next.js, nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx

I'm trying to host my app on `0.0.0.0:3000` and not localhost.

However each time I run the `nx serve career --port=3000 --host=0.0.0.0`

The app is hosted on:

`tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                LISTEN      9112/node`

Instead of:

`tcp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0 0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN   9112/node`

the difference is `:::` instead of `0.0.0.0`.

What am I doing wrong, how can I host the app on `0.0.0.0`

I'm using `nrwl/nx` and `NextJS` even if the port is correct the host is not.

Answer (score 11):

By default, the program will launch at `http://localhost:3000`. The default port can be modified by using -p, as in `npx next dev -p 4000`, or by using PORT, as in `PORT=4000 npx next dev`.

In terms of altering the hostname. You can also change the hostname from the default of 0.0.0.0. -H can be used to alter the default hostname, as in `npx next dev -H 192.168.1.2`.

[Find this and more from the NextJS official blog on Development](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development)

So in your case, it should be

```bash
npx next dev -H 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Sorry, I'm using npm/npx instead of nx.

Comment: Instead of using 0.0.0.0 you can also specify a hostname such as app.test.com

Answer (score 2):

`--host=0.0.0.0` is an option for `@nrwl/js:node`

For a `@nrwl/next:server` executor you can use the options `hostname` like `nx serve career --port=3000 --hostname=0.0.0.0`.

You should see the logs like

```
web-1  |
web-1  | > nx run web:serve:development --hostname=0.0.0.0
web-1  |
web-1  | info  - automatically enabled Fast Refresh for 1 custom loader
web-1  | event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.1s (166 modules)
web-1  | [ ready ] on http://0.0.0.0:4200
web-1  | wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
web-1  | event - compiled client and server successfully in 362 ms (172 modules)
web-1  | wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
web-1  | event - compiled client and server successfully in 423 ms (173 modules)
```

- ref1: https://nx.dev/packages/next/executors/server#options-playground
- ref2: https://nx.dev/packages/js/executors/node#options-playground

Comment: `--hostname` is what worked with `@nrwl/next:server` for me.

Answer (score 1):

and you can use this IP

```
127.0.0.1:3000
```

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: it should work
I use this IP for run localhost

Comment: Although 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 often play the same role, they are [not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/2227743). You cannot blindly change one for the other in all situations - well, you cannot, at least, expect that it would magically solve the issue everytime.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting other devices for debugging, make sure both devices are connected to same network (WiFi).

- Search for the ip address of the network you are connected, In my case I'm using Mac, you can enter this command in the terminal :
  `ipconfig getifaddr en0`
- In your Nextjs project run the project in this way:
  `npm run dev -- -H /your_ip_address/` 
  for example - `npx next dev -H 192.168.1.2`

Your's may be a different one. 
Explore more on - [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development)

**Happy coding :)**

Answer (score -2):

It's Working on my Laptop so you can try it http://127.0.0.1:3000/

Exampele = https://prnt.sc/obXNMHuWU5sq

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).