# Ubuntu 20.04: what are the security risks without firewall?

Tags: security, ssh, ubuntu-20.04, ufw

Ubuntu 20.04: what are the security risks without firewall?

Installed Ubuntu 20.04, but forget to enable firewall using ufw.

SSH 22 port: use keys(2048 bit) for login, no password.
Setting UsePAM=true, any risk?

Any other services that may have security holes without firewall, and hackers can break into the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Case for firewall

**Yes you should enable the firewall.** It's an important security layer.

Software has bugs. The firewall layer prevents some bugs or mistakes from causing harm.

Security is layered for the same reason airplanes have redundant systems. Even single engine airplanes are designed to glide when they lose thrust.

### SSH and Services You Know About

While proper SSH configuration is another topic, it illustrates a reason firewalls are needed. You're config is on the right track but without reading the entire man-page you're still unsure if it's secure.

If you're unsure about SSH, a firewall can limit access from source IPs that you define adding another layer.

SSH is but one of a handful of services you're running that might be accessible over the public internet. Sometimes services become open to the public unintentionally.

### Third Party Software

One type of bug is a software update or install that inadvertently opens a service and exposes that service to the public internet.

I frequently see application installs that open a private service bound to 0.0.0.0 when it should be bound to 127.0.0.1. If you don't know [the difference](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost), you aren't alone. Binding to 0.0.0.0 (or *) means open to the public internet.

This isn't just a user-workstation problem. Package managers are susceptible to this too.  NPM, Python PIP, and Apt all can run executables on your system.

### Checking for Open Services

Run `sudo netstat -n` to show active internet connections.

For example, here's output:

```
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4      31      0  192.168.1.17.53624     3.xxx.96.61.443        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.17.53622     162.xxx.35.136.443     ESTABLISHED
udp4       0      0  *.3722                 *.*
[...]
```

I do not know what udp port 3722 is but my system will accept traffic from ANYWHERE to that port.

## Closing

The firewall is a layer that lives lower in the network stack than applications and thus provides a layer to guard against configuration and application problems.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the firewall will prevent you accidentally exposing something you didn’t know was open - telnet, ftp, databases, Jupyter to name a few.

Regarding ssh with disabled password and ssh keys, it’s a good way to enable shell access but be aware that if there is no password on the ssh key, and the private key is stolen, then the thief will have access.

Also, remember ssh only encrypts transport. If you trust everyone who has or can obtain root access, that’s not a big deal, but if someone dishonest connects as root on the same host, then they can still spy on connections. Just something to be aware of.