# How to create a server in Mathematica container?

Tags: docker, sockets, wolfram-mathematica, zeromq, docker-network

I try to create a server in a Docker container using Wolfram Language. Docker parameters and Wolfram script, which starts a server inside it, are in the attached files:

- `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  wm:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app:ro
    ports:
      - "61104:8000"
    restart: on-failure
    hostname: wm
    container_name: wm
    working_dir: /app
    entrypoint: wolframscript -file /app/tcp_server.wls
```

- `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

RUN apt update -yq \
    && apt install -yq xz-utils curl gcc tzdata musl-dev python3-dev python3-pip clang \
    && dpkg-reconfigure tzdata \
    && apt install -y avahi-daemon wget sshpass sudo locales \
    locales-all ssh nano expect libfontconfig1 libgl1-mesa-glx libasound2 \
    build-essential mosquitto mosquitto-clients libnss-mdns mdns-scan nodejs \
    && apt clean \
    && apt autoremove -y \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

COPY ./Mathematica_12.1.1_LINUX.sh /root/

WORKDIR /root

RUN ./Mathematica_12.1.1_LINUX.sh --target ./extract --nox11 -- -auto -nodesktop \
    && systemctl enable avahi-daemon \
    && echo '!10.55.229.55' > /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/Configuration/Licensing/mathpass
```

- `tcp_server.wls`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)

httpResponseTemplate[text_] := StringTemplate[
  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: `2`
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 07:00:56 GMT

`1`"
][text, StringLength[text]];

listener = SocketListen[address,
    Module[{
      socket = #SourceSocket,
      message = #Data,
      func,
      query,
      result
    },
(*      Print[message];*)
      query = StringExtract[message, "\n" -> 1];
      func = StringCases[query, "GET /" ~~ f__ ~~ " HTTP/1.1" :> f, 1][[1]];
      result = ToExpression[func][];
      BinaryWrite[socket,
        httpResponseTemplate[
          "Hello, World!\nYou called the " <> func <> "\nResult is: " <>
              ToString[result] <> "\n"
        ]
      ]
    ]&
];


While[True, Pause[60]]
```

I found that described Wolfram server has a peculiarity. The first argument of Wolfram function `SocketListen` can not contain hostname from docker-compose file as a host address. However, absence of the docker hostname leads to inaccessibility of the server from the outside the container.

Need of the indication of the hostname can be proved by a netcat server, created inside the container. For example, the first variant below creates an accessible server, but the others — a server, inaccessible from the outside.

```sh
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l wm 8000
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l localhost 8000
echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l 127.0.0.1 8000
```

Variants for Wolfram, similar to the second and third ones, give the same result: inaccessibility from the outside. The `tcp_server.wls` file contains symbol `address`. It must be replaced with an exact string or integer before use. Here are Wolfram errors for all variants I've tried below.

`"http://wm:8000"` -> `SocketOpen::addrspec: The host specification http://wm:8000 is wrong because the port number conflicts with the scheme specification`

`"http://localhost:8000"` -> `SocketOpen::addrspec: The host specification http://localhost:8000 is wrong because the port number conflicts with the scheme specification`

`"http://127.0.0.1:8000"` -> `SocketOpen::addrspec: The host specification http://127.0.0.1:8000 is wrong because the port number conflicts with the scheme specification`

`"wm:8000"` -> `SocketOpen::zmqexception: A ZeroMQ exception was thrown - No such device (code 19)`

`"localhost:8000"` -> `SocketOpen::zmqexception: A ZeroMQ exception was thrown - No such device (code 19)`

`"127.0.0.1:8000"` -> `without errors, but inaccessible from the outside (accessible only from inside)`

`":8000"` -> `SocketOpen::addrspec: The host specification :8000 is wrong because it has an invalid domain specification`

`8000` -> `without errors, but inaccessible from the outside (accessible only from inside)`

The same was for other ports.

**How can I force Wolfram to listen `http://wm:8000` or how to change docker settings in the sense of a substitution of an actual hostname by 127.0.0.1 while transfer it via docker network?**

Before you build the Mathematica image, you need to change a licensing method inside the `Dockerfile` to the one you use (currently my network license is used) and download the linux installer `Mathematica_12.1.1_LINUX.sh` from Wolfram official site and put it into the folder with the three attachments from the beginning of this post.

Note, that this is a draft of a project. The full one will contain other services inside `docker-compose.yml`, e.g. Go server, that shall be accessible from the outside too.

Comment: You take a look at : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134637/running-mathematica-on-docker ?

Comment: @Brian Yes. Large amount of code is from there.

Comment: Just a short question regrading you sockets. Did it cause any problems in your implementation, when you leave socket object opened for each connection. By the time Wolfram accumulates Stream objects a lot... I faced an issue, when you force Close[socket], sometimes when the data is large it actually closes it before the whole thing was send.

Comment: @KirillVasin It's not been fully tested yet. Thank you for the issue description, I'll pay attention to it.

Comment: You may find Wolfram Research's very own Docker image helpful. Available at https://hub.docker.com/r/wolframresearch/wolframengine . The documentation also explains how to get a free "community" license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friends help to solve my problem.

The first argument of the function `SocketListen` should be `"0.0.0.0:8000"`. Then, `http://wm:61104/f` requested from the outside will link to the container.

The difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).