# What is running on host.docker.internal host?

Tags: docker, networking

I'm just curious, what is running on host.docker.internal host?

This service routes packages from docker container to services on host network.

But what exactly is it?

I found out that it's not gateway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll answer with a few things that I've found regarding the `Linux` implementation. I bet that the implementation details for Docker for Windows / Mac will be different.

**In short:** `host.docker.internal` is a Name. Every service that **runs on your host** and **binds** to the network interface that is also set as the Docker Daemon `host-gateway`, it can be accessed from inside a container at `host.docker.internal:[service_port]`.

#### Example

```
$ docker run -it --rm --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway alpine
/ # cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
... (it has a few other lines here) ...
172.17.0.1  host.docker.internal
```

#### How it works

- `--add-host` (applies to the container): it adds the last the line you see above to the container's `/etc/hosts` and this way `host.docker.internal` resolves to the IP address of `host-gateway`
- `host-gateway` (applies to the host): with a typical Docker installation, it's usually `172.17.0.1` (default bridge) but it can be changed/configured with `dockerd`, see the relative [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) :

> ```
> --host-gateway-ip ip      IP address that the special 'host-gateway'
>                           string in --add-host resolves to.  
>                           Defaults to the IP address of the default bridge
> ```

#### More digging...

You can check the Pull request that adds this feature: [#40007](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007)

The user describes that he did the following:

> What I did
> This PR allows containers to connect to Linux hosts
> by appending a special string **"host-gateway"** to `--add-host`
> e.g. `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` which adds
> `host.docker.internal` DNS entry in `/etc/hosts` and maps it to `host-gateway-ip`.
> This PR also add a **daemon flag** call `host-gateway-ip` **which defaults to
> the default bridge IP**.
> Docker Desktop will need to set this field to the Host Proxy IP
> so DNS requests for host.docker.internal can be routed to VPNkit

#### Historical context

I think the history behind all this is more or less the following:

- Linux users could access host services by using the IP address of the default bridge. The way Docker was setting up the networking offered that.
- Windows / Mac users also needed to access the host but the networking there had more complexity because of the different OS. So Docker for Windows / Mac introduced this `host.docker.internal` thing.
- It was also made available to Linux users as it's easier to use a Name than an IP address.

#### further reading:

- [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)
- [How to access host port from docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container/)
- [What is the difference between `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Comment: bottom line: host.docker.internal is a synonym for host-gateway which is a demon process routing requests to host apps