# Unable to reverse proxy traffic from Caddy (Docker) to Host Machine (Code-Server as Systemd)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, caddy

I posted this on Caddy, but hoping that posting it here can also get me help.

### 1. The problem I'm having:

I have been absolutely beating my head against a wall trying to understand if I can get Caddy which is running in a docker container to send traffic to a non-dockerized application on the host machine.

Essentially, I have Code-Server hosted locally on my machine as a systemd. I do not wish to dockerize Code-Server because I want the benefit of being able to directly interact with the host machine when using it. (Ie, direct terminal access, actual files on the machine, etc.)

I do not wish to run the container in Host or Bridge mode because I want Caddy to also be able to send traffic to any dockers in the future I plan to run. (Ie. portainer, personal projects, etc.) I also want the benefits of Docker Networking for containers.

Code-Server is listening at 0.0.0.0:8080.

When I run Caddy as a system service, no issues.

But if I dockerize Caddy everything I've googled and tried does not work.

So from my Domain I want to be able to capture traffic to pancakepuncher.com/code to code-server.

All the resources I've read indicate it should be as simple as finding the host machines IP for the docker network. Based on my config this appears to be 172.20.0.1 (Gateway of the docker network). I confirmed this with "hostname -I" and "ip addr ls".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### 2. Error messages and/or full log output:

```
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8478878,"msg":"using provided configuration","config_file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","config_adapter":"caddyfile"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8523543,"logger":"admin","msg":"admin endpoint started","address":"localhost:2019","enforce_origin":false,"origins":["//[::1]:2019","//127.0.0.1:2019","//localhost:2019"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8528814,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"server is listening only on the HTTPS port but has no TLS connection policies; adding one to enable TLS","server_name":"srv0","https_port":443}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8529165,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8530607,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"started background certificate maintenance","cache":"0xc00050ce80"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8539634,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling HTTP/3 listener","addr":":443"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.854263,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"srv0","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8543303,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"remaining_auto_https_redirects","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.854342,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic TLS certificate management","domains":["pancakepuncher.com"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8547323,"msg":"autosaved config (load with --resume flag)","file":"/config/caddy/autosave.json"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8547592,"msg":"serving initial configuration"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.855001,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"acquiring lock","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"warn","ts":1703182225.8559046,"logger":"tls","msg":"storage cleaning happened too recently; skipping for now","storage":"FileStorage:/data/caddy","instance":"849feaeb-f208-4f38-b501-203acbee6c19","try_again":1703268625.8559024,"try_again_in":86399.999999436}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8560653,"logger":"tls","msg":"finished cleaning storage units"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8569715,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"lock acquired","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8572795,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"obtaining certificate","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8589325,"logger":"http","msg":"waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["pancakepuncher.com"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182225.8589544,"logger":"http","msg":"done waiting on internal rate limiter","identifiers":["pancakepuncher.com"],"ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory","account":""}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182226.383774,"logger":"http.acme_client","msg":"trying to solve challenge","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com","challenge_type":"http-01","ca":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182226.5527983,"logger":"http","msg":"served key authentication","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com","challenge":"http-01","remote":"172.70.179.103:9556","distributed":false}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182226.7082229,"logger":"http","msg":"served key authentication","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com","challenge":"http-01","remote":"162.158.245.66:60992","distributed":false}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182226.830831,"logger":"http","msg":"served key authentication","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com","challenge":"http-01","remote":"108.162.245.141:38818","distributed":false}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182227.1281557,"logger":"http.acme_client","msg":"authorization finalized","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com","authz_status":"valid"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182227.1282039,"logger":"http.acme_client","msg":"validations succeeded; finalizing order","order":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/1477471916/230856017586"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182227.6197853,"logger":"http.acme_client","msg":"successfully downloaded available certificate chains","count":2,"first_url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/cert/03166f650dd285a08b4be12a2c0e1055d8ee"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182227.6204472,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"certificate obtained successfully","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182227.620613,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"releasing lock","identifier":"pancakepuncher.com"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"error","ts":1703182241.464922,"logger":"http.log.error","msg":"dial tcp 172.20.0.1:8080: i/o timeout","request":{"remote_ip":"172.71.22.45","remote_port":"10698","client_ip":"172.71.22.45","proto":"HTTP/2.0","method":"GET","host":"pancakepuncher.com","uri":"/code/","headers":{"Cf-Ipcountry":["US"],"Cf-Visitor":["{\"scheme\":\"https\"}"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"],"Cf-Connecting-Ip":["68.114.35.5"],"Cdn-Loop":["cloudflare"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile":["?0"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"],"Sec-Fetch-Mode":["navigate"],"Sec-Fetch-User":["?1"],"Sec-Fetch-Dest":["document"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8"],"Cf-Ray":["8392153ded76b0d9-ATL"],"Sec-Ch-Ua":["\"Google Chrome\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24\""],"X-Forwarded-For":["68.114.35.5"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform":["\"Windows\""],"Sec-Fetch-Site":["none"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip"]},"tls":{"resumed":false,"version":772,"cipher_suite":4865,"proto":"h2","server_name":"pancakepuncher.com"}},"duration":3.00356047,"status":502,"err_id":"u5naxwnsj","err_trace":"reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy.go:1267)"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182971.9205139,"msg":"shutting down apps, then terminating","signal":"SIGTERM"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"warn","ts":1703182971.9205818,"msg":"exiting; byeee!! ","signal":"SIGTERM"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182971.9206572,"logger":"http","msg":"servers shutting down with eternal grace period"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182971.9211495,"logger":"admin","msg":"stopped previous server","address":"localhost:2019"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182971.921201,"msg":"shutdown complete","signal":"SIGTERM","exit_code":0}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7606215,"msg":"using provided configuration","config_file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","config_adapter":"caddyfile"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"warn","ts":1703182977.7621322,"msg":"Caddyfile input is not formatted; run 'caddy fmt --overwrite' to fix inconsistencies","adapter":"caddyfile","file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","line":2}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.763228,"logger":"admin","msg":"admin endpoint started","address":"localhost:2019","enforce_origin":false,"origins":["//[::1]:2019","//127.0.0.1:2019","//localhost:2019"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7634773,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"started background certificate maintenance","cache":"0xc000689700"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.763528,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"server is listening only on the HTTPS port but has no TLS connection policies; adding one to enable TLS","server_name":"srv0","https_port":443}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7635436,"logger":"http.auto_https","msg":"enabling automatic HTTP->HTTPS redirects","server_name":"srv0"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7641044,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling HTTP/3 listener","addr":":443"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.764343,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"srv0","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7644136,"logger":"http.log","msg":"server running","name":"remaining_auto_https_redirects","protocols":["h1","h2","h3"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7644293,"logger":"http","msg":"enabling automatic TLS certificate management","domains":["pancakepuncher.com"]}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7656374,"msg":"autosaved config (load with --resume flag)","file":"/config/caddy/autosave.json"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7656577,"msg":"serving initial configuration"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"warn","ts":1703182977.7658086,"logger":"tls","msg":"storage cleaning happened too recently; skipping for now","storage":"FileStorage:/data/caddy","instance":"849feaeb-f208-4f38-b501-203acbee6c19","try_again":1703269377.7658052,"try_again_in":86399.999999484}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"info","ts":1703182977.7659295,"logger":"tls","msg":"finished cleaning storage units"}
caddy-caddy-1  | {"level":"error","ts":1703183082.006614,"logger":"http.log.error","msg":"dial tcp 172.20.0.1:8080: i/o timeout","request":{"remote_ip":"172.71.26.26","remote_port":"39636","client_ip":"172.71.26.26","proto":"HTTP/2.0","method":"GET","host":"pancakepuncher.com","uri":"/code/","headers":{"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"],"Sec-Fetch-Dest":["document"],"Cf-Ipcountry":["US"],"Sec-Ch-Ua":["\"Google Chrome\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24\""],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"],"Sec-Fetch-User":["?1"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8"],"Cf-Connecting-Ip":["68.114.35.5"],"Cdn-Loop":["cloudflare"],"X-Forwarded-For":["68.114.35.5"],"Cf-Ray":["839229c2eb36243f-ATL"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile":["?0"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform":["\"Windows\""],"Sec-Fetch-Mode":["navigate"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"],"Cf-Visitor":["{\"scheme\":\"https\"}"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"Sec-Fetch-Site":["none"]},"tls":{"resumed":false,"version":772,"cipher_suite":4865,"proto":"h2","server_name":"pancakepuncher.com"}},"duration":3.003401594,"status":502,"err_id":"g2henjp1x","err_trace":"reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy.go:1267)"}
```

### 3. Caddy version:

v2.7.6

### 4. How I installed and ran Caddy:

#### a. System environment:

Debian 12 Docker Compose

#### b. Command:

```
docker compose up -d
```

#### c. Service/unit/compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  caddy:
    image: caddy:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - caddy_proxy
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - "2019:2019"
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "443:443/udp"
    volumes:
      - /home/admin/docker_stack/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - /home/admin/docker_stack/caddy/site:/srv
      - /home/admin/docker_stack/caddy/caddy_data:/data
      - /home/admin/docker_stack/caddy/caddy_config:/config

volumes:
  caddy_data:
    external: true
  caddy_config:

networks:
  caddy_proxy:
    external: true
```

#### d. My complete Caddy config:

```
pancakepuncher.com {

    handle_path /code* {
        reverse_proxy 172.20.0.1:8080
    }
}
```

I've tried so many things.

I'll list off some of it:

I've tried using all the IP's listed under hostname -I except for the Public IP.

I've tried configuring code-server to listen on the "Gateway" IP. I've tried giving it it's own IP in that same "Network". I've set it to 0.0.0.0, localhost, 127.0.0.1. Best I can discern is that the recommended for an application to accept traffic universally is 0.0.0.0.

I've configured a basic "whoami" container alongside Caddy and Code-Server and can confirm that Caddy sends the traffic to the whoami app at "/whoami" but it just can't seem to route to Code-Server on the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
services:
  caddy:
    ...
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

**`Caddyfile`**

```
pancakepuncher.com {
  handle_path /code* {
    reverse_proxy host.docker.internal:8080
  }
}
```

Hope that helps…

Comment: I know I'm supposed to avoid comments saying 'thanks!' but wow thanks so much!! This was a precisely the solution I needed.

I'll try to make my comment more useful by posting a link to a SO post [explaining what host.docker.internal is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72827527/what-is-running-on-host-docker-internal-host).