# Docker Port Forwarding for FastAPI REST API

Tags: docker, port, fastapi

I have a simple [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) project called `toyrest` that runs a trivial API. The code looks like this.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

__version__ = "1.0.0"

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return "hello"
```

I've built the usual Python package infrastructure around it. I can install the package. If I run `uvicorn toyrest:app` the server launches on port 8000 and everything works.

Now I'm trying to get this to run in a Docker image. I have the following Dockerfile.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3

# Create a user.
RUN useradd --user-group --system --create-home --no-log-init user
USER user
ENV PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH

# Install the API.
WORKDIR /home/user
COPY --chown=user:user . ./toyrest
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r toyrest/requirements.txt
RUN pip install toyrest/ && \
    rm -rf /home/user/toyrest


CMD ["uvicorn", "toyrest:app"]
```

I build the Docker image and run it, forwarding port 8000 to the running container.

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 toyrest:1.0.0
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I try to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get no response.

Presumably I am doing the port forwarding incorrectly. I've tried various permutations of the port forwarding argument (e.g. `-p 8000`, `-p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000`) to no avail.

This is such a basic Docker command that I can't see how I'm getting it wrong, but somehow I am. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The app is listening on the loopback interface, inside the container. You cannot expose this by publishing a port. You need to bind to the private network interface, preferably using 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add this line to your`CMD` in  ̀dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "toyrest:app","--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**EDIT**

The reason this works is because this makes uvicorn run inside the container on 0.0.0.0 NOT on 127.0.0.1

0.0.0.0 is exposed by docker because it is the private network interface of the docker container. You cannot SEE 127.0.0.1 from outside the container.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing and why.

Comment: Thanks. Adding "--host 0.0.0.0" to the CMD works. Why is it necessary though?

Comment: well I m not very good in docker but as i know the docker container have his own network so the `uvicorn` server inside the docker re listening to the docker nertwork `localhost` so when you try to communicate with the `uvicorn` from outside the container you re not using the same `localhost` runing `uvicorn`on `0.0.0.0` can solve the problem you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/18317391

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) might prove helpful to future readers as well.