# How can I resolve FLASK 404 error: URL was not found on the server?

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 error:

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

```
    from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.route("/")
    def index():
        return "hello world"

    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="80")
```

```
    * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
    * Running on http://127.0.0.1:80
    * Running on http://192.168.29.41:80
    Press CTRL+C to quit
    192.168.29.41 - - [12/Mar/2023 15:32:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
    192.168.29.41 - - [12/Mar/2023 15:32:43] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2023 15:37:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to run your Flask application on a localhost port, i.e `http://127.0.0.1:5000` for example, see this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost), and the [Flask quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/), in particular the "Externally Visible Server" section.

I'd recommend:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route("/")
def index():
    return "hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

if you're using `python file_name.py`, this starts the server on `http://127.0.0.1:5000` or:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

if you're using `flask run`