# What will happen if listening 0.0.0.0 and loopback with a same port

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm confuse when I listen both `0.0.0.0` and `localhost`(or `127.0.0.1`) with the same port. It has different behavior when using different IP connects to it.

Here is my golang demo

```golang
func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    addrs := []string{"127.0.0.1:8080", "0.0.0.0:8080"}
    wg.Add(len(addrs))
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        go lis(addr, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    _, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
}

func lis(addr string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    wg.Done()

    for {
        conn, _ := listener.Accept()
        fmt.Printf("%v: accepted%v\n", addr, conn)
    }
}
```

- when dialing with `localhost`, `0.0.0.0` accepted.
- when dialing with `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.1` accepted.
- when dialing with `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` accepted.
- when dialing with `192.x.x.x`(my Ip), `0.0.0.0` accepted.

I also have a try with IPv6.

- when dialing with `[::]`, `127.0.0.1` accepted.
- when dialing with `[::1]`, `0.0.0.0` accepted.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but isn't listening to '0.0.0.0' sufficient to also include 127.0.0.1?   Please read up the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Comment: @ewokx Servers launched by users are unpredictable

Comment: What will happen is that it won't work. You can bind any number of sockets the same port as long as (1) they all use a different local IP address and (2) none of those is 0.0.0.0. Surprising you didn't already discover that when you tried it.

Comment: @ewokx Perhaps you could make that into an answer. Since 0.0.0.0 does indeed encompass ALL IP addresses.

Comment: Too many questions here! You mentioned the network as `tcp` not `tcp4` or `tcp6`, so it binds both ipv4 & ipv6 addresses. You can verify with `netstat -tlnp` if you happen to run `linux`. You passed the network addresses list to functions to run concurrently, so isn't that expected to liston on all those network addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior could vary by API, OS, and even OS version.

Process A could be listening on just the loopback:port, while process B could be listing to "everything else":port.

But the general idea (although an API could add a layer above it), is to have interfaces receive data.

In most operating systems, 127.0.0.1 is received on an interface often named "loop", and it is the LOOPBACK interface. The critical behavior is that a loopback isn't accessible externally (esp. via addresses on a physical interface).

Classically that meant only loopback addresses (127.0.0.1 or anything in the 127. class A network) would work.

But some operating systems would internally handle other addresses as local, so the address of any interface on the system could/would work. (I recall this was a flag in late-stage Solaris, circa 9-11).

Personally, I don't think you should be able to open connections for any IP address in 0.0.0.0/24, but I'm sure some setups do, or worse, let the traffic out on the wire.