# Dockerfile for azure-search-openai-demo App

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, quart

I am trying to Dockerise an app which uses the [Quart](https://pypi.org/project/Quart/) package.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11 AS backend-build

COPY backend /app/backend

WORKDIR /app/backend

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "-m", "quart", "--app", "main:app", "run", "--port", "5000", "--host", "localhost", "--reload"]
```

Docker image gets built but when I start it and try to access the web at http://localhost:5000/ I see `HTTP ERROR 403`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` in `CMD`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost) for why.
- Run the container with `-p 5000:5000`.

```
├── backend
│   ├── main.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── Dockerfile
```

`main.py`

```
from quart import Quart, render_template, websocket

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route("/")
async def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Quart==0.19.4
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.11 AS backend-build

COPY backend /app/backend

WORKDIR /app/backend

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "-m", "quart", "--app", "main:app", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--reload"]
```

Screenshot below shows container running and demo page being accessed on http://localhost:5000.

[image]