# Django: Using Different Templates for Production

Tags: django

In my base.html template which is imported in every Django template, I have a block with the Google Analytics script:

```
<!-- GOOGLE ANALYTICS -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    bla bla...
</script>
```

I would like to have this script only included when in production, but not during development. Is there a solution for this comparable to the solution in setting.py?

```
import socket

if socket.gethostname() == 'my-laptop':
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
else:
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
```

Anybody who knows of a template tag, or should I do my own one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add your DEBUG variable to a context processor and just put an IF around that block.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

```
from django.conf import settings
def debug_context(request):
    return {'DEBUG': settings.DEBUG}
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if DEBUG %}
    STUFF
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively you could make the context processor return anything you want to key off of, anything in your settings file or otherwise.

Comment: Xealot, thank you for your advice which I implemented. Everything works fine after including the custom context processor in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Easiest solution to implement!

Comment: Glad to hear, I've been using this particular implementation for 3+ years now and it's still the simplest I know of. Hopefully you'll start thinking of context processors to solve other problems now as well.

Answer (score 3):

In `settings.py`，Check `debug` is `True`, also add:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = (
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost',
)
```

Then you can use things in your template like this:

```
{% if debug %}
<span>This is debug</span>
{% else %}
<span>This is production</span>
{% endif %}
```

If want to change to production, set `debug` to `False`.

Ref:
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen such a template tag yet.

I'm more inclined to use different setting.py files for production and dev, and include analytics code as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629696/deploying-google-analytics-with-django/629715#629715).

This solution allows for a simpler template, and gives you the option to use different analytics code in different deployments of the same app.

Comment: That link looks exactly as what I have been looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The template is probably not the best place to handle this.

usually, you'd write a [context preprocessor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) that will process the request and add a flag to your context (such as PRODUCTION = True). Then you can use a simple if statement in the template, or better yet, write a simple custom tag that will hide that implementation detail from the template.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629696/deploying-google-analytics-with-django/629715#629715).

Comment: Arthur, thank you for you helpful answer! I choose the answer from Xealot since it helped me to implement my first ever context processor - not really difficult ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I do the following on lots of sites and it seems to work really well.

Then in my static media file directory I have a copy of base.css and base_dev.css. I do all my development in the base_dev.css file then merge it into base.css before I launch.